# firebase function state pending and return undefined

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm trying to make an input form that will check if the data exists in firebase database, below is the code that I used to check the data :

```
    if(element.validation.codeunique) {
       function checkCode(inputcode) {
          firebaseUsers.orderByChild('code')
          .equalTo(inputcode).once('value')
          .then( snapshot => {
              let thecode = null;
              if(snapshot.val()){
                  thecode = false;
              } else {
                  thecode = true;
              }
              console.log(thecode)
          })
       }
       let checkcode = null;
       checkcode = checkCode(element.value);
       console.log(checkcode)
       const valid = checkcode;
       const message = `${!valid ? 'Code Exists':''}`;
       error = !valid ? [valid,message] : error
   }
```

in database i have a data :
users
       -L3ZeHOI7XOmP9xhPkwX 
            -code:"DEM"

when I entered data **DEM** at the form :
**console.log(thecode)** result is false (which is the result that i want)




and when i entered another data **ASD** at the form :
**console.log(thecode)** result is true(which is the result that i want)

so the firebaseUsers actually is giving me the feedback/data that I want,
 but when I tried to get the data at valid with true/false,

this is the code that I originally used:

```
if(element.validation.codeunique) {
    function checkCode(inputcode) {
        firebaseUsers.orderByChild('code')
        .equalTo(inputcode).once('value')
        .then( snapshot => {
            if(snapshot.val()){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        })
    }
    const valid = checkCode(element.value);
    const message = `${!valid ? 'Code Exists':''}`;
    error = !valid ? [valid,message] : error
 }
```

the **valid** shows = undefined,
my goal is to make the valid shows true/false,
could someone help me, and point out, what did i do wrong?

*I make the first code just to point out that the firebase is actually working
*the second code is the one that I originally used

Comment: The Firebase calls you are making return promises. `checkCode()` doesn't actually return anything (and thus is `undefined`).  You either need to use async/await to wait on the promise to finish and then grab result or use promises properly.

Comment: Also, does ESLint tell you any errors?  It seems like the linter would point this out.

Comment: @JamesPoag maybe i need to use async/await, i will try this. and about the promises, what should i do to make a properly promises?

the ESLint is not showing me any errors, thats why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done it outside of the function above and by checking it when the user submit the form, and if the code exists, i direct it to form again :

```
firebaseUsers.orderByChild('code')
   .equalTo(mycode)
   .once('value')
   .then (snapshot => {
     if(snapshot.val()) {
        alert("Code Exists, Please Choose another");
        this.props.history.push('/myscreen')
   } else {
       //submit the data
   }
```

hopefully this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues that are standing out to me.

First, the code that you use originally was using `return` inside of the function's `if / else` conditional. I believe this is correct, you'll want to go back to doing that.

Second, the `firebase.orderByChild()` function that you are calling is a Promise as it has a `.then()` statement appended to it. What this means is that the function does not synchronously finish executing and return a value. The code below that promise is being run while the firebase function is still processing.

Give this a shot and see if it works, and if you have any further errors beyond the promise.

```
if(element.validation.codeunique) {

   function checkCode(inputcode) {
      firebaseUsers.orderByChild('code')
      .equalTo(inputcode).once('value')
      .then( snapshot => {
          if(snapshot.val()){
              return false;
          } else {
              return true;
          }
          console.log(thecode)
      })

  }
  let message = checkCode(element.value) ? 'Code Exists':'Code Does not Exist';
}
```

Comment: `checkCode` still doesn't return anything in this version.

Comment: Hi Mike Abeln, 
Thank you so much for your reply,

i've tried the code above

and the function gives me undefined answer,
what it needs is boolean (true/false),
i'm still trying to find out whats is wrong with this.

anyway thank you for your reply

Comment: @JamesPoag Yup, the checkCode still doesn't return anything, thanks